# SQLite DELETE slow when primary key is two columns

Tags: sqlite, boolean, where-clause, sql-delete, bitwise-operators

I have a SQLite table defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  colA INTEGER NOT NULL,
  colB INTEGER NOT NULL,
  colC INTEGER,
  PRIMARY KEY (colA, colB));
```

One of the inner-loop operations I perform in a large transaction is:

```
DELETE FROM mytable
  WHERE (colA = ?) & (colB = ?);
```

This operation seems to be bottlenecking my application.  When I run strace to see what the application is doing, I see it making large sequences of sequential 1024-KiB `pread64` calls on the database file, suggesting that maybe that the deletion actually requires a linear scan of the table, rather than a simple index lookup.

I'm assuming there's an index on the primary key, but maybe I'm doing something wrong.  My question is whether there's a way to speed up these delete operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operator `&` is the `bitwise AND` and **not** the `boolean AND` operator.

If you use the `boolean AND` operator then the primary key will be used to make the execution faster:

```
DELETE FROM mytable
  WHERE (colA = ?) AND (colB = ?);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/OCJ58znH) with the execution plan.